# Oracle Spatial sdo_aggr_union filling inner rings

Tags: aggregate-functions, oracle-spatial

While trying to perform an aggregation over a number of shapes which include inner rings (i.e. holes; see example pictures) I used sdo_aggr_union() from Oracle Spatial (12c), and realized that this operation creates new geometries "filling" the holes, which is something I didn't expect actually.

I wonder if that is expected, or it's a bug in 12c, or if there's something I can do to create a geometry which does not fill those holes, and create instead inner rings in the merged geometries.

1 - Original shapes (note some cuts, between adjacent shapes):
[image]

2 - Result of sdo_aggr_union() (cuts are gone, but holes became new geometries)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I verified that this operations works fine in 19c, where holes are preserved by aggregate union. It's possible this was a bug in 12c, but 12c is now very old and past end-of-life. It is also possible that you have validation errors in your geometries. I suggest you move to a currently supported database version, validate and (if needed) rectify your geometries. You'll find validation functions in the package [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_GEOM-reference.html) and the rectify function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-0ADE1234-7E8C-493B-8F1D-443DB4588BD8). Then try the aggregate union. I'll be glad to assist further if needed.